# Bulk Insert records in Postgres using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am trying to do multiple insert row using node-postgres, I want id to be created dynamically and return those ids

Following approach, I am using

```
const insertArray = [['kunal@test.com',1000,'abcdef'],['kunal1@test.com',1000,'fedkcn']]
let query1 = format(`INSERT INTO users VALUES %L returning id`, insertArray);
const newClient = new Client();
await newClient.connect();
let {rows} = await newClient.query(query1);
```

I am getting errors as
invalid input syntax for type integer: "kunal@test.com",
how can we skip id?

Tried using CSV option via copyfrom also getting the same issue

```
 const stream = client.query(copyFrom(`COPY users FROM STDIN (format csv, DELIMITER ',', HEADER)`))
       const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./tmp/copy.csv');
```

**copy.csv**

```
"email","amount","address"
'kunal@test.com',1000,'abcdef'
```

**USERS table schema**

```
id       email    amount   address
Integer. String.  Integer. String.
```

Not sure how to auto-generate id and return the rows containing new id.

Cannot provide the col name also, as this functionality will also be used by other schemas.

If I provide id it works fine

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Inserting (either by `insert` or `copy`) without specifying column names is positional operational in order of column definition. In other words here `insert into users values ...` is the same as `insert into users(id, email, amount, address) values ...`. However, your data does not have the same structure. The solution is to specify your columns:

```
... INSERT INTO users(email, amount, address) VALUEs...

... COPY users(email, amount, address) FROM STDIN ...
```

Comment: My question is on that itself, i won't be able to add column names as this method is shared by many tables

Comment: It is a **single** statement or copy. So create one for each. *In a RDBMS do not try to share things that are **not the same***. Your other option is to write a procedure to: Create a parameter table for each input file with each column and appropriate order. Then dynamically build the query/copy and execute the generated statement.  Perhaps another option generate the query/copy from the data dictionary (information schema). However, both are slower and more error prone than just creating a separate statement/command for each file.